# Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type '_' and 'String'

Tags: swift, reduce

I am new to swift.
I want to use the function reduce to concatenate names in an array
my code:

```
let names = ["ZZZZZZ", "B", "AA", "CCCC", "EEEEE"]
let sum = names.reduce(0) {
return $0 + $1
}
```

and I get this error
Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type '_' and 'String'

Comment: It looks like you're trying to sum value of numeric type and a string.

Comment: You should probably change the `0` to an empty string `""`. If you are trying to concatenate strings.

Comment: Of course `joined()` is the way to go but  `reduce("", +)` would work as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to `reduce` strings the default value must be an empty string `""`

```
let sum = names.reduce("") { return $0 + $1 }
```

Actually

```
let sum = names.joined()
```

does the same.

Comment: Thank u, it was very helping